# Ways to arrange 24 different books in 4 bookshelves

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways can Beth arrange 24 different books in four bookshelves
>   such that there's at least one book in each bookshelf.
>
> (For any of these arrangaments, consider that in each bookshelf the
>   books must be put one next to each other, and the first book on the
>   left).

First of all, sorry if doesn't make sense, I tried my best translating it. This is from Grimaldi's discrete mathematics book, so if anyone has this book feel free to edit my post.

I thought this was a really simple combinatorics problem, so what I did was, if there are 4 bookshelves and 24 books, then I could write this as:

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=24$ with $x_i \geq 1$ $\forall i$

So that's equivalent to $x_1'+x_2'+x_3'+x_4'=20$, so that would be ${23\choose 20}$.

But the solutions says it's $24!{23\choose 20}$, where does the $24!$ come from? I mean, by doing that, aren't you counting the cases where, for example, there's an empty bookshelf?

Comment: The $24!$ arises because the books are different.  Your count would be correct if the books were indistinguishable.

Comment: To picture this clearly, suppose there were only four books.  Then, of course, Stars and Bars (or common sense) gives the answer $1$, since there must be exactly. 
 one book  per shelf.  But the answer to this question would then be $4!$ since there are $4!$ ways to assign the books, one to a shelf.

Comment: @lulu oh that makes sense! Your last example helped me so much. Thank you!!!!